# ResponseText or something dosen't work using Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, responsetext

Heyy can somebody help me ?
i have this issue that still do know who to resolve... titanium is show a error that says this "Uncaught ReferenceError: responseText is not defined", i tried very option but hmmm don't work.
this is my code

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function(){
    alert("voltou ao js");
    var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    if (response.logged == true)
    {
        alert("voltou ao js e funca");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("-.-");
    }
};

button1.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{

    var params = box1.values ;
    xhr.open("GET","http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste_demo_grafica/Resources/teste.php?");
    xhr.send(params);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL is unresponsive. You should get a web debugging proxy like fiddler or charles so you can see your web traffic.

Also, remove the trailing ? after the address, what is with that?

Also, try doing a "POST" instead of "GET" some servers do not allow that verb.

Also, you will want error handlers in cases like this.

Comment: now it says "Message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"

Comment: @VeraRodrigues Seems like you are still getting a blank response then, or the JSOn is malformed. Please check it in fiddler first.